# Decrypt / Password SQLite for Query

Tags: c#, uwp, sqlcipher

I need to unlock a password protected SQLite file add data, then email the Password Protected file, all my Queries & email work fine until I password protect the file using DB Browser (SQLCipher),

I have been following the example on GitHub SQLite-Net which gives this example

```
var options = new SQLiteConnectionString(databasePath, true,
key: "password");
 var encryptedDb = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(options);
```

But I get an error when I add the var options to the SQLiteAsyncConnection, the error says

> cannot convert from SQLite.SQLiteConnectionString to String

```
    private async void pickPeriod()
    {
         List<string> periodArray = new List<string>();

        SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();

        try
        {
            string fileName = "fieldnames5.sql";
            var databasePath = Path.Combine   (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, fileName);
            var options = new SQLiteConnectionString(databasePath,   true,   key: "Wi_Day!");
            var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(options);
            {

                await conn.CreateTableAsync<storeNames>();

                try
                {


                    var periodNo = await conn.QueryAsync<storeNames>  ("SELECT Period FROM WkNos");
                    foreach (var period in periodNo)
                    {

                        string myresult = period.Period.ToString();


                        periodArray.Add(period.Period);


                        HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(periodArray);
                        string[] result = new string[set.Count];
                        set.CopyTo(result);

                        periodArray.AddRange(result);

                    }
                    pdNumPick.Items.Clear();
                    pdNumPick.ItemsSource = periodArray;
                }
                catch
                {
                    pdNum.Text = "<-No Data->";
                }

            }
        }

        catch
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("File does not exits");

        }
    }
```

I just need to unlock the SQLite file & add data & relock

Comment: The solution is in the error message "cannot convert from SQLite.SQLiteConnectionString to String", means that the constructor for SQLiteAsyncConnection does not take a ConnectionString as a parameter, but rather a string

Comment: Can you give a clue how to fix the error? the snipet is exactly as per the example given by Cipher so I would of hoped it would just work, I spent till midnight on this yesterday but I do not have the knowledge to resolve the error

Comment: Turns out, the SQLiteAsyncConnection only takes a string as a parameter called a connection string, which looks something like described [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/). I have never used SQLite with .NET but I assume the SQLiteConnectionString has some property/ method to get this string?

Comment: Instead of `(options)` write `(options.ConnectionString)`

Comment: Thank you for the help, this has resolved the error, but the picker still has no results while the SQLite file is encrypted, so I guess the key is not working?

Comment: shouldn't you use something like `conn.SetPassword(...)`?

Comment: I tried this method earlier in the week, however ".SetPassword" is not in the Library, so I cannot select it as an option, I tried ".Execute" & PRAGMA Key but this did not work either

Comment: actually you've used SQLCipher, so I'm not sure if you can use some generic SQLite .NET library to access the DB, most probably you are limited to use of `SQLCipher for .NET`.